# How do I get rid of / replace MS word old trial version?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, microsoft-word

The trial version of Microsoft word is expired which was included as an additional software on my laptop when I bought it. I bought a MS office live CD and removed the old version from control panel. When I installed the new one, it says it's expired again. What should I do to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

It probably installed the new program using the old trial activation code. You'll have to re-activate the software using the product key for the CD you bought. Then it will recognize it as the one you purchased and you shouldn't see that message anymore.